# Strange error when filling a data adapter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, memory

I am receiving the following error in my code (c#, .Net 3.5, VS2008) when I try to connect to an Excel sheet and fill a OleDbDataAdapter with the results of a query. First the error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is
>   corrupt.

And here is the code, which is honestly pretty simple:

```
var excelFileName = @"c:\Metadata_Tool.xlsm";
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;", excelFileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Video Tagging XML]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "VTX");

DataTable data = ds.Tables["VTX"];

foreach (DataRow myRow in data.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn myColumn in data.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write("\t{0}", myRow[myColumn]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I get the error on the line `adapter.Fill(ds,"VTX");`. I did find a microsoft forum post saying to turn on JIT optimization in VS2008 from the Tools/Options/Debug/General menu, but this did not seem to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be generated from within the ACE provider.  My guess is that it's because your connection string is wrong.

Instead of:

```
var excelFileName = "c:/Metadata_Tool.xlsm";
```

You should have:

```
var excelFileName = @"c:\Metadata_Tool.xlsm";
```

Note the backslash instead of forward slash.  You need the `@` character at the front to prevent the backslash from being escaped.  You also don't need the `string.Format` at all - you aren't formatting anything on this line.

Comment: I gave this a try, and although you are right about the formatting, unfortunately that did not solve the problem. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Tim C: Are you sure the file is there?  With the correct permissions applied?  Have you tried opening it in Excel?  Have you tried this same code on a fresh, blank Excel file that you created by hand with only a couple of rows?

Comment: It does seem to be with the Excel file! The file was in the correct location and had all of the permissions, but when I changed to another file, it worked fine. Something is corrupt about this one. Thank you!